# Excel table referencing - is there a speed factor (penalty or bonus) for the different approaches

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I work an a gigantic excel worksheet (approximately 40,000 rows over dozens of columns) where every cell mirror references the same cell in another worksheet (Never mind the strange architecture, coming from the limitations of the software exporting this excel behemoth, I have to take this for granted) about 150,000 cell referencing in this worksheet alone. I wonder what is the most speed efficient way to reference the other table cells:

- The classic excel method: Using somehting like: `=value(datasheetname!c2)`
- Using the relatively new Table cell reference like: `=table_name[@c_rowname_or_number]`

In order to make this gigantic worksheet responsive, I already need to disable autocalculation, so every minor performance improvement would be great for me.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Few questions: 1. Are you sure it's 40000 columns and not rows? ;-) 2. What do you mean with "where every cell mirror references the same cell in another worksheet"? 3. do you need to cast strings to values (using the value function) or was this just an example 4. Are there any other complex calculations happening? I don't think tables  will improve or decrease speed significantly, though not sure

Comment: @PeterAlbert You are right about the columns, small mix up, now edited to fix. I need the value, but since I'm getting values anyway from the sql into the other worksheet maybe this is redundant (need to check).  referencing is exactly the question = a cell that calls the value from another cell.4. not many complex calculations (some vlookups, also in the process of optimizing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'm not sure if you're looking into the right issue - Excel's performance of simply linking cells is quite high - in my example workbook, I linked 5M cells and it took just 0.4" to run the calculation. Normally, even a few `VLOOKUP` formulas on large datasets will have a much bigger performance impact than any number of linked cells. Check out [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/547083/how-do-you-speed-up-searching-large-columns-in-excel/547100#547100) for an explanation how to improve speed here.

To answer your question, I just ran some timers on the workbook with 5M cells.

If I linked them by a simple reference (`=Sheet1!A2`), I got the following results:
10x `Application.CalculcateFullRebuild`: 47" 
10x `Application.CalculateFull`: 3,7"

With the table notification (`=Table1[@Column1]`) I got these results:
10x `Application.CalculcateFullRebuild`: 193" (4.1x)
10x `Application.CalculateFull`: 5,7" (1.54x)

So in both cases, the table notification is significantly slower. In your case, the `.CalculateFull` is probably more applicable, as Excel only builds the calculation tree when it loads the file or updates - and else only does a recalc.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that dynamically named references (using OFFSET) have a significant impact if they are very large.  I would say that if you have any of these in your sheet and they don't necessarily have to be there (set number of columns, etc) then you should change them to static references.